# How do I update a product that is partially defined then later add additional product details to it

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a product that is partially defined when it is first created. It is assigned a product code and a category to which it belongs. Later when the marketing group provide details, these details need to be updated by adding the details to the product. These are done by different groups. A batch job obtains the product partial product details from one database and the product details from a relational database and then updates the product with the product details in a MongoDb database. Here is the objects as they exist initially. The Product details get assigned a product code and category and written to the MongoDB database. The batch job runs nightly checking for product details for the Product and then should update the Product with the ProductDetails when they become available in the relational database. Here are the objects:

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document
public class Product {
  @Id
  private long productCode;
  private String category;
}


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductDetail {
  private long productCode; // matches the product code in Product
  private String description;
  private int quantityOnHold;
  private BigDecimal price;
  private String warehouseLocationId;
  private float discountFactor;
  private String orderDescCode;
  private String vendorId;
}
```

I am wondering what's the way to update the Product with the Product details. Do I create the equivalent Product document and add the Product details as a nested document? Is there a way to simply update the existing document by first modeling it as it is i.e. just the Product with its 2 fields and then add the ProductDetail? I'm relatively new to using Spring Data Mongo, so I don't know what the approach should be that makes the most sense, please help.

Comment: Try to simplify your question. it is quite difficult to read and understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection="product_collection")
public class Product {
  @Id
  private long productCode;
  private String category;
  private ProductDetail  productDetail;
}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductDetail {
  private String description;
  private int quantityOnHold;
  private BigDecimal price;
  private String warehouseLocationId;
  private float discountFactor;
  private String orderDescCode;
  private String vendorId;
}
```

You can use spring-data-mongodb to do that.

You can use the following methods to update documents.

1. save – Update the whole object, if “_id” is present, perform an update, else insert it. Notice that an "_id" field is generated by spring-data-mongo and mapped to the field annotated with @Id.
2. updateFirst – Updates the first document that matches the query.
3. updateMulti – Updates all documents that match the query.
4. Upserting – If no document that matches the query, a new document is created by combining the query and update object.
5. findAndModify – Same with updateMulti, but it has an extra option to return either the old or newly updated document.

The easiest way to find and update an document in my opinion is to use mongoRepository :

```
import com.globallogic.spring.mongodb.model.Book;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
  
public interface ProductRepo
    extends MongoRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

And then inject your mongoRepository in a service class:

```
@Service
public interface ProductService {
    ProductRepo productRepo;
    //injecting productRepo into you service
    public ProductService(ProductRepo productRepo) {
        this.productRepo = productRepo;
    }
    
    public void updateproduct(Long productCode, ProductDetail productDetail ) {

        
        Product pFromMongo = productRepo.findOne(productCode);
        //set whatever you want on pFromMongo
        pFromMongo.setDetail(productDetail);
        ....
        //And then save the productCode. This will add or update product detail
        productRepo.save(pFromMongo);

        
    }
}
```

The resulting product in MongoDB will look like :

```
{
    productCode : 1,
    category: "pCateg",
    productDetail : {
         description : "description",
         quantityOnHold : 11,
         price : 12.33,
         warehouseLocationId : "warehouseLocationId",
         discountFactor : 1.0,
         orderDescCode : "orderDescCode",
         vendorId: "vendorId"
     }
}
```

You can take a look at this presentation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReqMU6bmPNM&ab_channel=JavaTechie

Comment: I have no control over the initial Product creation.  That creation is a completely group and they own the core product information. My group works with marketing to provide product description to update it with the ProductDetail when it becomes available.

Comment: Ok. So a product have one or more related detail (is there a one to one or one to many relationship between Product and ProductDetail ? 

have you taken a look at @DBRef ?  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mongodb-dbref-annotation

Comment: Yes, it is a one-one relationship between Product and ProductDetail

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please let me know if this addresses your issue.